# Ansible is there a modify-volume task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-ebs

I want to use ansible to run [modify-volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-volume.html) and increase the volume size of instances with multiple ebs volumes attached. However, it seems that the [ec2_vol](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/ec2_vol_module.html) task does not have a modify feature. How can I resize attached volumes using ansible?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but it's worth revisiting since now it's possible to do modify a volumes with Ansible only.

The following playbook will resize first EBS volume attached to a running instance.

```
---
- name: Prepare
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: Gather information about a particular instance using ID
          amazon.aws.ec2_instance_info:
            filters:
              tag:Name: "{{ ansible_host }}"
              instance-state-name:
                - running
          register: instance_info        

        - name: Resize volume
          amazon.aws.ec2_vol:
            instance: "{{ instance_info.instances.0.instance_id }}"
            id: "{{ instance_info.instances.0.block_device_mappings.0.ebs.volume_id }}"
            modify_volume: true
            volume_size: "{{ ec2_instance_volume_size }}"
          register: resize_volume
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Reboot if volume is resized so partition is resized by cloud-init
      reboot:
      when: resize_volume.changed
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of answers, depending on your interest in "pure ansible:"

1. use the `shell:` task and spawn `aws` a bunch of times to figure out what the state is of the volume, and then use `modify-volume` if necessary
2. use a hybrid approach to use [`ec2_vol_facts:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/ec2_vol_facts_module.html#ec2-vol-facts-module) followed by `command: aws ec2 modify-volume ...` if necessary
3. "fork" the [`ec2_vol.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.5/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_vol.py) into your `playbook/library` and update your copy to [accept volume-id and size](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.5/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_vol.py#L591-L592) and call the `modify_volume` equivalent there. You can then optionally submit that change back to ansible as a PR and see if they accept it so others can benefit

   Ansible will see your `ec2_vol.py` and supersede the globally installed one, which is good in that you get to continue to use all the `ec2_vol` behavior, and bad in that other people who read the playbook may wonder what's going on with that new behavior

Ansible is nice in that you can do things several ways, and suboptimal in that their release cycle and PR acceptance leaves much to be desired

Comment: Yea I essentially wound up doing something similar to 2) I collected volume ids with ansible then modified them with ruby using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html#modify_volume-instance_method